# Select Child Elements - Input Tags Problems

Tags: html, css

I have a Div with inside several elements, some of theme share some common attributes, in my case `input[type="submit"] input[type="text"]` share `border: 0; margin: 0px;`

With this code I'm not able to apply the Style to both Input Tags.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

```
#cse-search-box input[type="submit"] input[type="text"] /*Problem here*/
{
    border: 0;
    margin: 0px;
}
#cse-search-box input[type="text"]
{
    position:relative;
    top:-6px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0px !important; 
}
#cse-search-box input[type="submit"]
{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: Red;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a comma:

```
#cse-search-box input[type="submit"],
#cse-search-box input[type="text"]
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With your version, you were selecting an `input` inside an `input`.

To fix, you need to separate them with a comma and make sure they both follow the same selector path:

```
#cse-search-box input[type="submit"], #cse-search-box input[type="text"]
```